# Navigation properties for self-referenced tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I've this category class.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Not knowing how many levels each one of them will have, I'll keep category, sub-categories, and so forth in the same table. `ParentCategoryId` is the FK.

Is this the right way of configuring the self join table?

```
//Navigation
  HasRequired(c => c.ParentCategory)
       .WithMany(c => c.ChildCategories)
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCategoryId);
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

By doing the following configuration:

```
//Navigation
HasRequired(c => c.ParentCategory)
    .WithMany(c => c.ChildCategories)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCategoryId);
```

You're saying that every created category have a parent category and that parent is required. This will not work because root categories don't have parent. Only sub-categories have parent category. So parent category is optional. If parent is required, it will be impossible to insert root categories.

So you need to make your `ParentCategoryId` property optional (by using nullable => `int?`) and your entity should look like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Your fluent configuration should look like this (notice I use `HasOptional` method):

```
HasOptional(c => c.ParentCategory)
    .WithMany(c => c.ChildCategories)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentCategoryId);
```